# codeigniter, how to call active class to navigation in single page website?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am working on a single page website, I have following navigation bars:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><i></i><a href="#home"  class="active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#accommadation" class="">Accommodation</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#activities" class="">activities</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#gallery" class="">>gallery</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#contact" class="">>contact</a></li>   
</ul>
```

its working on the **section id** in the section tag. like

```
<section id="home">
<section id="accommadation">
```

how to give `class="active"` for navigation?

Comment: question is not so clear

Comment: something like `<a href="#accommadation" class="<?=($this->uri->segment(2) == 'accommadation' ? 'active' : '')?>">Accommodation</a>`

Comment: url segment is same for all. Here, when we click on a navigation it will navigate to corresponding id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><i></i><a href="#home"  class="nav_menu active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#accommadation" class="nav_menu ">Accommodation</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#activities" class="nav_menu ">activities</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#gallery" class="nav_menu ">>gallery</a></li>
    <li><i></i><a href="#contact" class="nav_menu ">>contact</a></li>   
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav_menu').click(function(){
            $('.nav_menu.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not dependent on Codeigniter or PHP as it is Single page website you need some client side javascript code or use jQuery like,

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav a[href^=#]').on('click',function(e){
        $('.navbar-nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        // if you want some animation for the element to scroll then use animate()
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.href).offset().top},900);
    });
});
```